# Show UIMenuController from UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem, uimenucontroller

I have a navigation bar with a bar button item on the right. I would like to open a popup menu when pressing that button.

Can anyone tell why this doesn't work:

```
@IBAction func quickJumpClicked() {

    let menu = UIMenuController.sharedMenuController()
    menu.menuItems =
        [UIMenuItem(title: "Test me", action: Selector("deleteLine")),
        UIMenuItem(title: "Test me", action: Selector("deleteLine")),
        UIMenuItem(title: "Test me", action: Selector("deleteLine"))]
    menu.setTargetRect(self.navigationController!.toolbar.subviews[1].frame, inView: self.view.superview!)

    becomeFirstResponder()
    menu.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: have you implemented 'canPerformAction' and 'canBecomeFirstResponder'  methods ?

Comment: Only: canBecomeFirstResponder. It returns "true". Anything else is needed?

Comment: yes, 'canPerformAction' also must be implemented so all menu items will be  visible

Comment: Should I just return "true"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your `targetRect` is functioning as expected. I'm assuming your objective is to get a menu to appear from the `UIBarButtonItem`.

One thing you could do is rewrite your `IBAction` to include a sender, then just get the frame of the sender – in your case, a `UIBarButtonItem`.

That would look something like this:

```
@IBAction func quickJumpClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    let menu = UIMenuController.sharedMenuController()
    menu.menuItems =
        [UIMenuItem(title: "Test me", action: Selector("deleteLine")),
            UIMenuItem(title: "Test me", action: Selector("deleteLine")),
            UIMenuItem(title: "Test me", action: Selector("deleteLine"))]
    menu.setTargetRect(sender.view!!.frame, inView: self.view)
    menu.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
    becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

You may also be missing two methods. `canPerformAction(_:withSender:)` enables custom commands in the UI, and `canBecomeFirstResponder()` allows your controller to become first responder and receive messages from `UIMenuController`.

For example:

```
override func canPerformAction(action: Selector, withSender sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if action == Selector("deleteLine") {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: Works good, but the menu is covering the navigation bar. Any way of putting items top to bottom direction and putting the menu below the item?

Comment: I'm not sure that vertically stacking items is possible. To position the menu lower, you could take the frame and add a small y-offset. You may want to consider using a different class entirely. UIAlertController allows popovers on iPhone and iPad since iOS 8.